# Apply discount on checkout when a specific quantity of products are purchased with a specific taxonomy

Tags: commerce, rules

I have Commerce Discount installed that enables me to create a discount on a product with a certain taxonomy. However I only want this discount applied when a customer selects at least three of these products with the taxonomy.

It there a way I can update the rule created with the discount to achieve this?

This has already been logged as an enhancement [Add option to specify amount of products that needs to be orderd](https://www.drupal.org/node/2580863)

But I need to resolve this before my site can go live

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by adding a condition to the rule that was created by the discount.

And
Total quantity of selected product comparison

Answer (score 0):

There is another module that should work [Commerce Taxonomy Conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_taxonomy_conditions). I believe it allows you to add a quantity per taxonomy term discount condition.